# How to configure ini file to send mail with php

Tags: php, wamp, sendmail, wampserver

I am using wampp server and I try to send mail with php script. But I am getting errors.

I configured php.ini file in different ways and wamp server does not have a sendmail file.

So how to setup this?

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost


; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from =myMail1@gmail.com

   <?php


    $from = "myMail1@gmail.com";
    $to = "test_one@outlook.com";
    $subject = "Checking PHP mail";
    $message = "PHP mail works just fine";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);


?>
```

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at
>   "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and
>   "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in
>   C:\wamp64\www\sendMail\index.php on line 9

I want to eliminate this error. I restarted my server couple of times.

Comment: You need a SMTP server to send your email, if you are using gmail, your server would be smtp.gmail.com and your port would be 465 (SSL) or 587 (TLS). As far as I remember, you also need to set some configuration in your gmail account in order to allow sending emails through SMTP.

Comment: which OS do you use? Here is documentation about setting up sendmail on Linux: https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/wamp/troubleshooting/send-mail/

Comment: For developing on Windows I used this tool: https://toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/ It stores messages in specified folder not sending them actually

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use your own server as smpt server (have you?) try with smtp.gmail.com over port 587

https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600